# What should be in .gitignore for wearable native C/C++ Tizen Studio project?

Tags: git, gitignore, tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

So, what should be in `.gitignore` for wearable native C/C++ Tizen Studio project? There are solution for some separate files like [this](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/sdk-ide/what-.rds_delta-file?langswitch=ko), but seems not complete `.gitignore` file sample for wearable native C/C++ application.

Comment: You may follow these https://github.com/TizenTeam/vlc-tizen/blob/master/.gitignore, https://github.com/cisco-open-source/kodi/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: Thanx! If you want, make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may follow these `.gitignore` from the open source Tizen projects

- [VLC Tizen](http://github.com/TizenTeam/vlc-tizen/blob/master/.gitignore):

> ```
> /.cproject
> /.checkers
> /.rds_delta
> /.sdk_delta.info
> /.sign
> /crash-info/
> /res/res.xml
> /vlc/
> /Debug/
> /Release/
> /lib/*.so*
> /lib/*.a
> /emotion/
> /libvlcpp/
> /medialibrary/
> *.tmp
> *~
> res/edje/*.edj
> ```

- [Kodi](http://github.com/cisco-open-source/kodi/blob/master/.gitignore)